# Unable to call loaction.state inside componentDidMount in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on reactjs project where i have to get the data form Component B to Component A . i am successfully able to get the detail, after A component is fully mounted and perform some action such as click . I want the data to be returned when i mount my component in componentDidMoount or render function . I am unable to get the desired data how can i reslove this?. bellow is my code.

Component B (component which create's the data i need and pass it to edititeratoin)

```html
<Redirect to={{ pathname: '/EditIteration',state: {editdata: userdata.userid , editstartdate:userdata.startdate , editenddate:userdata.enddate , editname:userdata.name} }} />
```

Componnet A

```html
locationState()
  {
    console.log("Message",this.props.location.state.editdata);
  }

  componentDidMount()
  {
    // console.log("Message",this.props.location.state);
     this.locationState();
  }
```

Comment: Please create stackblitz link to reproduce your issue

Comment: okay . i will do that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React router v4 - How do you access the state that is passed via Redirect?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46876888/react-router-v4-how-do-you-access-the-state-that-is-passed-via-redirect)

Comment: @Hemadri Dasari please go through my question i am able to get the state in normal methods but i am unable to get it in compoentDidMount or render function